# Авторизация git на windows, c#

Tags: c#, windows, git, github

Помогите разобраться! Пишу маленькую прогу умеющую выполнять некоторые команды git. Хочу добавить авторизацию в этой программе. Как мне вызвать вот такое окошко, и в дальнейшем вытащить оттуда токен?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так я получаю данные из "Диспетчера учётных данных", но, как я понимаю, данные там появятся только после вот этой авторизации в "окошке", скажем так...

(Если пользователь не авторизован, то переменная 'creds' будет равна null)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или же если знаете как сделать авторизацию по проще, например парой get/post запросов, то буду рад узнать

Comment: А какую библиотеку используете для гита? Кстати, код надо вставлять текстом, с не скриншотами. Вроде нп в первый рас вопрос создаете, а допускаете в оформлении такие новичковые ошибки.

Comment: dll: LibGit2Sharp

Comment: Используйте авторизацию по ssh ключам, тогда и спрашивать ничего не придется.

Comment: @user7860670 не все используют ssh)